# Operating Rightmost/Leftmost n-Bits, Not All the Bits of A Integer Type Data Variable

Tags: c, optimization, bit-manipulation

In a programming-task, I have to add a smaller integer in variable `B` (data type `int`)

to a larger integer (20 decimal integer) in variable `A` (data type long long int),

then compare A with  variable C which is also as large integer (data type `long long int`) as `A`.

What I realized, since I add a smaller B to A,

I  don't need to check all the digits of `A` when I compare that with `C`, in other words, we don't need to check all the bits of `A` and `C`.

Given that I know, how many bits from the right I need to check, say n-bits,

is there a way/technique to check only those specific n-bits from the right (***not all the bits of A, C***) to make the program faster in `c` programming language?

Because for comparing all the bits take more time, and since I am working with large number, the program becomes slower.
Every time I search in the google, bit-masking appears which uses all the bits of `A, C`, that doesn't do what I am asking for, so probably I am not using correct terminology, please help.

**Addition:**

***Initial comments of this post made me think there is no way but i found the following -***

[Bit Manipulation by University of Colorado Boulder
(@cuboulder, after 7:45)](https://youtu.be/qEmcEqjuhQY)

> ...the bit band region is accessed via a bit band alías, each bit in a
> supported bit band region has its own unique address and we can access
> that bit using a pointer to its bit band alias location,  the least
> significant bit in an alias location can be sent or cleared and that
> will be mapped to the bit in the corresponding data or peripheral
> memory,  unfortunately this will not help you if you need to write to
> multiple bit locations in memory dependent operations only allow a
> single bit to be cleared or set...

Is above what I a asking for? if yes then
where I can find the detail as beginner?

Updated question:

Is there a way/technique to check only those specific n-bits from the right (***not all the bits of A, C***) to make the program faster in `c` programming language (or any other language) that makes the program faster?

Comment: `A == C` is almost certainly going to be faster, more readable, and more maintainable than anything you could cook up comparing a variable number of bits.

Comment: @RetiredNinja does `A==C` compare every bit until it find a mismatch or it checks all corresponding bits of `A, C` regardless any mismatch? where  do I get such information about such  operation (that actually works in cpu)?

Comment: You can check instruction timings of various modern x86 processors here: [uops.info](https://uops.info/table.html) (there are similar lists elsewhere for different types of processor) Almost nothing is "bit-by-bit" on modern processors. That exists, but not for simple ALU operations such as comparison.

Comment: In case you're interested in some theoretical aspects, you can look up (for example) the Kogge-Stone adder, and the Wallace multiplier

Comment: Bit-banding is used to add bit-addressed memory aliased to byte-addressed memory, it is not related to performing "narrow" arithmetic operations

Comment: It depends on your program. If I understand correctly, you want to check if A+B=C right? If A and C don't change for many B, then if C - A is not a value you can store in B, then you don't even need to check it, or if it is, then you can check it against C - A cast to the smaller type, though that might not give much if any performance improvement.

Comment: Yes you do need to check all bits.  For example, 0x3fffffffffffffff + 1 = 0x4000000000000000 so all value bits change.

Comment: One way to gain some CPU cycles here would be by design. As @dbush stated previously, with no predeterminate *state* of `A` and `C`,  any since all bits can change in `A` following `B` addition. However, if you start with a defined state of `A` equaling `C` *before*  `B` addition, you can just check if `B` is zero or not to ascertain the fact that `A` remains equals `C` *after* the addition. Anyway, with actual CPUs and compilers, the addition as the comparison would be very probably direct register like, thus there will be no cycle gain except in very uncommon edge cases.

Comment: Note also that with a "check only if `B` is zero or not" design, your compiler will very probably optimize it in a way to check `B` first and do the `A` addition only for a non zero `B`, whatever the way you write it in C. Generally speaking, the most efficient way to speed the things up is choice of algorithm and design as actuals C compilers will be very efficient to produce the most efficient machine code for your "problem description" C code. Anyway, even to this day, it's still very useful to know the "under the cover" of CPUs and compilers to take some advantages.

Comment: If you're working on bit level, my first advise would be to use unsigned data types. If I get you right, you want to perform A + B on all bits, preserving the result, and then only compare the last n bits of that result to C. One way to go about this for n < 32, would be to get a pointer to the second part of the result variable, and make the comparison on that. However I doubt this would bring about a big speedup. `unsigned long long res = A + B; uint32_t *comp = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>( &res)[1]; ` Something like that

Comment: @dbush plz read the post again, I wrote "Given that I know, how many bits from the right I need to check, say n-bits,"... the problem description ensures no such scenario will occur like you described, i do understand it makes you feel weird but that is the scenario we have, please reconsider.

Comment: @Michael That would mean you know something about the values beforehand, in which case you need to be explicit about exactly what that is.  In any case, you can only operate on a full byte at a time, so unless you have a measurable performance impact from doing this comparison you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Regarding "bit band region": This is very specific. Only for ARM CPUs (not Intel, or AMD). Only specific memory areas. And most likely comparing a few single bits is slower than comparing all e.g. 32 or 64 bits at once.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that comparing fewer bits is faster might be true in some cases but is probably not true in most cases.

I'm only familiar with x86 CPUs. A x86-64 Processor has 64 bit wide registers. These can be accessed as 64 bit registers but the lower bits also as 32, 16 and 8 bit registers. There are processor instructions which work with the 64, 32, 16 or 8 bit part of the registers. Comparing 8 bits is one instruction but so is comparing 64 bits.

If using the 32 bit comparison would be faster than the 64 bit comparison you could gain some speed. But it seems like there is no speed difference for current processor generations. (Check out the "cmp" instruction with the link to [uops.info](https://uops.info/table.html) from @harold.)

If your long long data type is actually bigger then the word size of your processor, then it's a different story. E.g. if your long long is 64 bit but your are on a 32 bit processor then these instructions cannot be handled by one register and you would need multiple instructions. So if you know that comparing only the lower 32 bits would be enough this could save some time.

Also note that comparing only e.g. 20 bits would actually take more time then comparing 32 bits. You would have to compare 32 bits and then mask the 12 highest bits. So you would need a comparison and a bitwise `and` instruction.

As you see this is very processor specific. And you are on the processors opcode level. As @RawkFist wrote in his comment you could try to get the C compiler to create such instructions but that does not automatically mean that this is even faster.

All of this is only relevant if these operations are executed a lot. I'm not sure what you are doing. If e.g. you add many values B to A and compare them to C each time it might be faster to start with C, subtract the B values from it and compare with 0. Because the `compare`-operation works internally like a subtraction. So instead of an `add` and a `compare` instruction a single `subtraction` would be enough within the loop. But modern CPUs and compilers are very smart and optimize a lot. So maybe the compiler automatically performs such or similar optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

Try this question.

> Is there a way/technique to check only those specific n-bits from the right (not all the bits of A, C) <strike>to make the program faster in c programming language (or any other language) that makes the program faster</strike>?

Yes - when `A + B != C`.  We can short-cut the comparison once a difference is found: from least to most significant.

No - when `A + B == C`.  All bits need comparison.

---

Now back to OP's original question

> Is there a way/technique to check only those specific n-bits from the right (not all the bits of A, C) to make the program **faster** in c programming language (or any other language) that makes the program faster?

No.  In order to do so, we need to out-think the compiler.  A well enabled compiler itself will notice any "tricks" available for `long long + (signed char)int == long long` and emit efficient code.

---

Yet what about *really* long compares?  How about a custom `uint1000000` for `A` and `C`?

For *long* compares of a custom type, a quick compare can be had.

First, select a fast working type.  `unsigned` is a prime candidate.

```
typedef unsigned ufast;
```

Now define the *wide* integer.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define UINT1000000_N (1000000/(sizeof(ufast) * CHAR_BIT))

typedef struct {
  // Least significant first
  ufast digit[UINT1000000_N];
} uint1000000;
```

Perform the addition and compare one "digit" at a time.

```
bool uint1000000_fast_offset_compare(const uint1000000 *A, unsigned B,
    const uint1000000 *C) {
  ufast carry = B;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < UINT1000000_N; i++) {
    ufast sum = A->digit[i] + carry;
    if (sum != C->digit[i]) {
      return false;
    }
    carry = sum < A->digit[i];
  }
  return true;
}
```